# If I do an online degree from a Canadian University, can I add it in Canadian immigration as Canadian education?

Tags: immigration

I want to do a degree from Canada. If I do a masters/MBA online from Coursera from a Canadian University, can I add it as Canadian education in my application for immigration?

Comment: Distance education from a university would count the same, so I think that you can list this as canadian education.

Comment: Would it be as part of Express Entry for skilled immigrants? An online program may still need ECA under the scheme, and note that Coursera is US, not Canadian.

Answer (score 1):

While an online program might be accepted, it may still require assessment, as "you got your education outside Canada." If the intention is the use a degree to enhance or expedite emigration, you should determine whether remote coursework is equivalent and whether the program is part of an accredited Canadian institution.

If you've already completed the program, you may want to go ahead with the [Educational Credential Assessment (ECA)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp), to verify acceptance of your credential, in advance of immigration application.

As an aside, Coursera is a US-based program which doesn't currently list participation by any Canadian institutions.